# CiviCRM SearchKit Field Style

Tags: searchkit, css

I have built a table in SearchKit and I want to colour the rows based on a person display name. Whilst the available styles are useful I would like to expand these to have more colours available I have searched on Google and looked through Civi docs but could not find much information. Any ideas would be much appreciated. See the image below for further detail:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can add your own class with the Other option and then load some css targeting that class, either via a custom css file (under Admin > System Settings > Resource URLs), from your CMS or in an extension. The custom css file option is the easiest, though it will load on all pages.

Comment: Thanks this is great, ideally I would prefer not to use the Resource URLs as I don't want it to appear anywhere else but the table. We are running on top of Drupal, are there any existing extensions that supply the required functionality ? Appreciate the help.

Comment: I've used CSS Injector for this on D7 (Asset Injector on D8).

Comment: Yeah I did try that is there any way to prevent the CSS applying across the whole website? I only want to color the rows if they match the set display name? Appreciate all your help thus far.

Comment: You should be able to set the path for the rule in CSS Injector. Unless that doesn't work with angular pages?

Comment: It should work if embedded on an afform. Afform routes are "real" pages :)