How to override CSS in SearchKit results
I'm using WordPress 6.6.2 (self-hosted) and CiviCRM 5.76.2.  I'm exposing a SearchKit result as a grid, and I want to do some styling on the result.  As suggested in https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/45252/295, I've added a custom CSS file with my desired styles:
.crm-search-display-grid-layout-3 {
  align-items: start;
  justify-items: start;
}

I'm loading my custom CSS by setting the "Custom CSS URL" property in the "Settings - Resource URLs" screen.
It's getting loaded in the browser, but it appears to take lower precedence than CiviCRM's hard-coded file crmSearchDisplayGrid.css:

Is there something I can do to change this precedence?

Your question is actually about the basics of how css works, and not specific to SearchKit. In css, ids take priority over classes. I suggest you read up on css specificity, but the quick answer is you can add !important at the end of your rules.

I’m not sure I understand - both the selectors shown here are using classes, .crm-search-display-grid-layout-3 and .crm-search-display-grid-container specifically.

Well, adding !important will do what you want. But to answer your question: if specificity is the same (e.g. both selectors use a single class) then the order of the files matters. You could try adding your css file to the page footer instead of the header.

I guess my question is more like "how am I supposed to style SearchKit results", without using precedence overrides like this.  It definitely is working now for me, but it doesn't seem like the natural or intended way for it to work.
